# apple apns feedback information

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am writing a procedure which is related to apple apns feedback. I have a problem now.

As the apple doc says:

The Feedback Service

If a provider attempts to deliver a push notification to an application, but the application no longer exists on the device, the device reports that fact to Apple Push Notification Service. This situation often happens when the user has uninstalled the application. If a device reports failed-delivery attempts for an application, APNs needs some way to inform the provider so that it can refrain from sending notifications to that device. Doing this reduces unnecessary message overhead and improves overall system performance.

"the application no longer exists on the device"

"This situation often happens when the user has uninstalled the application"

Is there any other situation? If there is not any other situation, does it mean the feedback token number is the user who uninstalled the app?

thanks

Comment: Also, if the device has been kept in a place where it doesn't get any wifi or cellular data

Comment: @Aadhira there is not wifi or 3G signals, but I didn`t get any information from apns feedback :( Is it time delay?

Comment: `there is not wifi` or `there is wifi`? If there is no wifi or cellular data, you may not get feedback..

Comment: @Aadhira I don`t agree with you. If there is no wifi or cellular data, I should get feedback on the server.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376) to get some better description.